# Wordpress Child theme fails to override parent theme css

Tags: wp-admin, wp-enqueue-style, css

I've installed the [Faxhion](https://themeforest.net/item/faxhion-model-agency-wordpress-theme/14163526) theme for a client, and I've **successfully** created a child theme. However I'm somehow not able to override the parent themes css.

Similar questions such as [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/255069/activating-child-theme-breaks-website-blank-page-error-500?newreg=be6f6361a6264ae4a47c08e67dc552b5) & [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/273941/how-to-override-parent-theme-function-through-the-child-theme) have been asked, I've followed the instructions on both, and I've managed to see that my child theme css is being applied as the below picture shows.

[image: dev tools]

If you look at the bottom right of dev tools you can see that I've given `body{background: blue;}` in the child theme's style.css.

**The issue** is that as you can see the `main.css` is cancelling out the child theme's style.css. I'm not sure how to fix this as I'm new to WP Dev.

Here is the child theme comment header:

```
/*
Theme Name: Faxhion Child
Author: Jordan Miguel
Template: faxhion
Version: 0.1
*/

body {
    background: blue;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

And here is how I'm using the parent theme css **note that `@import` did not work for me so I'm using `functions.php as stated`[here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/255069/activating-child-theme-breaks-website-blank-page-error-500?newreg=be6f6361a6264ae4a47c08e67dc552b5) -

```
    <?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    //* Parent CSS
    wp_enqueue_style( 'faxhion', 
      get_template_directory_uri() . '/main.css' );

    //* Child CSS
    wp_enqueue_style( 'faxhion-child', 
      get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', [ 'faxhion' ], );
} );
```

**EDIT** Here is the order of the `stylesheets` in the `head`. The parent theme css is linked above the child theme css, should that be changed?

```
 <link rel='stylesheet' id='faxhion-css'  href='http://www.rareselect.co.uk/wp-content/themes/faxhion/main.css?ver=4.8.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='faxhion-child-css'  href='http://www.rareselect.co.uk/wp-content/themes/faxhion-child/style.css?ver=0.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='plugins-css'  href='http://www.rareselect.co.uk/wp-content/themes/faxhion/assets/css/plugins.css?ver=4.8.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='fontawesome-css'  href='http://www.rareselect.co.uk/wp-content/themes/faxhion/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css?ver=4.8.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Comment: Can you show the order of the `stylesheets` in the `<head>` ?

Comment: @DavidLee I can't add the picture as I do not have 10 reputations. Ive inspected the head and can see that the parent them css is above the child theme `style.css`

Comment: @DavidLee I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the issue, there is a second call to `main.css` :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="faxhion-css" href="http://www.rareselect.co.uk/wp-content/themes/faxhion/main.css?ver=4.8.1" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="faxhion-child-css" href="http://www.rareselect.co.uk/wp-content/themes/faxhion-child/style.css?ver=0.1" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="plugins-css" href="http://www.rareselect.co.uk/wp-content/themes/faxhion/assets/css/plugins.css?ver=4.8.1" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="fontawesome-css" href="http://www.rareselect.co.uk/wp-content/themes/faxhion/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css?ver=4.8.1" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="style-css" href="http://www.rareselect.co.uk/wp-content/themes/faxhion/assets/css/main.css?ver=4.8.1" type="text/css" media="all">
```

The one you are calling with `id="faxhion-css"` its loading nothing its a `404` because `main.css` its not there, the actual `main.css` file its inside `/assets` and its already being loaded somewhere. 
You have 2 options:
**Option 1**:
Dont call the parent CSS and put `'style'` as a dependency:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {

    //* Child CSS
    wp_enqueue_style( 'faxhion-child', 
      get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', [ 'style' ], );
} );
```

`'style'` its the ID of the main stylesheet.

**Option 2**:
Remove the main stylesheet and add it back:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'style' );//removing main.css
    //* Parent CSS
    wp_enqueue_style( 'faxhion', 
      get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/main.css' );//adding it back

    //* Child CSS
    wp_enqueue_style( 'faxhion-child', 
      get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', [ 'faxhion' ], );
} );
```

Second option will work but i dont recommend it, the first option should work too, if you are having 500 errors its more likely the `<?php` and `?>` are not matching and 1 is missing.

Comment: This code broke my website with `HTTP error 500` unfortunately

Comment: Is there a simple method of removing the second call to `main.css` ?

Comment: 500? are you missing a `php` closing tag? the code its your same code but without the  `wp_enqueue_style` of the parent and replaced `'faxhion'` by `'style'`

Comment: Ok great, so its kind of working. When I reload the page, I see the `body{background:blue}` is working as the page flashes blue for a split second, before going back to the original styling. Inspect the page again to see.

Comment: that is because of `#csmx-page {
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}` that div its over `body` that is just CSS now, the good thing its the order of the files is the correct one now.

Comment: Ok so how can I get rid of this `#csmx-page` styling?

Comment: With CSS in your child-theme, like you did with `body`, the idea of a Child-theme is to change small aspects of the parent theme  a child theme inherits the look and feel of the parent theme and all of its functions, but can be used to make modifications to any part of the theme. In this way, customizations are kept separate from the parent theme’s files.